How to fill in clang format excetable path when using VSCode plugin?
When not filled in, it would report an error of
"The 'clang-format' command is not available. Please check your clang-format.executable user setting and ensure it is installed."
, so I filled in
"(A long path)....vscode\extensions\ms-vscode.cpptools-1.22.0-win32-x64\LLVM\bin"
, but it became invalid after updating the version. I had to rewrite it again, which was very troublesome.I need a long-term usable filling phrase.

"(A long path)....vscode\extensions\ms-vscode.cpptools-1.22.0-win32-x64\LLVM\bin\clang-format.exe", actually.

how did you get a clang-format executable in there? was it there when you installed the extension? (I don't have one...) did you put it there yourself? why don't you use an installer that puts it in the system PATH for you?

@starball It was there when I installed the extension. I tried to install llvm with clang(4.45GB), and added “\clang+llvm-18.1.8-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\bin“ to the system PATH, but it didn't work. If I fiil in "\clang+llvm-18.1.8-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\bin\clang-format.exe"(or just clang-format.exe anywhere), it does work, but I don't think this solution is reliable.
